# read child elements with same node name using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file with nodes with the same name

```
<Test>
<testing>
    <testId>2233</testId>
    <name>frank</name>
    <machine>3</machine>
    <img>1.jpg</img>
    <img>5.jpg</img>
    <img>001.jpg</img>
    <img>100.jpg</img>
    <img>1125.jpg</img>
</testing>
</Test>
```

The controller

```
public ActionResult TestMachine(int id = 0)
    {
XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var Test = Xdoc.Descendants("testing").Select
        (imm => new test
        {
            TestId = Convert.ToInt32(imm.Element("testId").Value),
            Name = imm.Element("name").Value,
            Machine = imm.Element("machine").Value,
            Image = imm.Elements("img").Select(img => new Images {
            Url = img.Element("img").ElementValueNull()
            }).ToList() 

    }).Where(i=> i.TestId == id).FirstOrDefault();
return View(test);
    }
```

The value of list img are empty
any suggestions appreciated

Comment: you are looking for a subelement `img` on `img`, change to `Url = img.ElementValueNull()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is with

```
...
Image = imm.Elements("img").Select(img => new Images {
        Url = img.Element("img").ElementValueNull()
        }).ToList()
```

because img is already an `<img>` element, but you query it for its child `<img>` element.

Change it to

```
Image = imm.Elements("img").Select(img => new Images {
        Url = img.ElementValueNull()
        }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
public ActionResult TestMachine(int id = 0)
{
    XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
    var Test = Xdoc.Descendants("testing").Select
    (imm => new test
    {
        TestId = Convert.ToInt32(imm.Element("testId").Value),
        Name = imm.Element("name").Value,
        Machine = imm.Element("machine").Value,
        Image = imm.Elements("img").Select(img => new Images {
        Url = img.Value
        }).ToList() 
    }).Where(i=> i.TestId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(test);
}
```